# Scala build Immutable Map with for... yield comprehension, throw exception on duplicate key

Tags: scala

Here is the challenge (Scala 2.11):

```
(for (i <- -3 to 3) yield (f(i), i)).toMap
```

f(): Int => Int is an unknown argument here, which is passed into my code. The resulting map will be the "inverse" of the function over the bounded space.

This will work fine if

```
f(i: Int) = i * 2
```

but it will **NOT** work fine if

```
f(i: Int) = i * i
```

because, eg f(-2) = 4 and f(2) = 4 which makes duplicate keys and the second overwrites the first

My question is: How can I throw and IllegalArgumentException  when there are duplicate keys...(ie telling the user that his/her function is not "invertable" over the bounded space)

I know I could use a mutable.Map and write a loop, as opposed to a for comprehension (eg using tail recursion), which does a "map.get" on each iteration and if already exists, throw...., otherwise add to map.

Is there an immutable way of doing it?

For extra points I also need to check that f(i) is within the bounds (-3..3) and ignore if not...

Comment: Side remark, but... Don't throw. Return a `Try` or something.

Comment: @Jubobs : fair point in Scala. However in this case the signature of my method has to return a   Int => Int   (ie using the map once built). There is no allowance for a Try

Comment: @OliverSchonrock i think what @Jubobs meant was you could then filter out all `scala.util.Failure` by using `collect`: `Seq(Try{ throw new IllegalArgumentException }, Try(1)).collect{case scala.util.Success(num) => num }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down into smaller steps, it becomes clear that the for-comprehension returns a vector. `toMap` is what creates the map. however, in your scenario `foldLeft` is more appropriate than `toMap`.

```
  val f = (i:Int) => i * i
  val pairs = for (i <- -3 to 3) yield f(i) -> i
  val result = pairs.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int]) { case (map, (k, v)) =>
    if(map contains k)
      map //or throw IllegalArgumentException here
    else
      map + (k -> v)
  }
  println(result)
```

here's a bit more stepped out (but functionally identical) answer:

```
  val f = (i:Int) => i * i
  val pairs = for (i <- -3 to 3) yield f(i) -> i

  val zero = Map.empty[Int, Int]
  def putIfAbsent(map:Map[Int, Int], pair:(Int, Int)):Map[Int, Int] =
    pair match { case (k, v) =>
      if(map contains k)
        map
      else
        map + (k -> v)
    }

  val result = pairs.foldLeft(zero)(putIfAbsent)
  println(result)
```

Comment: thanks. I couldn't figure out how to use foldLeft to do what I wanted..(sorry bit newbie to Scala)..can you help?

Comment: sure, updated. similar to answer provided by @rahilb

Comment: that looks great thanks! I couldn't work out how to "use the immutable Map" for checking ...while I am still adding to it as if it were a Mutable...

Comment: not that it's important here, but how will that perform over a space for i of a couple of thousand values? It seems your code suggestion creates a "new map" N=2000 times, each with a new element appended. That's a lot of copying...Not sure what the characteristics of "contains" are, but seems like this might be > O(N^2) ? Cost of being immutable?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock there's certainly no "copying". adding to an immutable map in Scala is effectively constant time [[1](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics)]. also, have a look at the [Benchmarking Scala Collections](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html) article.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could foldLeft on your range instead of using a for comprehension, e.g:

```
(-3 to 3).foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int]){ case (result, next) => 
   val answer = f(next)
   result.get(answer).fold(result + answer -> next)(_ => throw new IllegalArgumentException)
}
```

I didn't double check the APIs of all the classes used, so that code probably won't compile, but something like it should.